# How to get React Project to work Because NPM Start Wont Work

Tags: html, css, reactjs, npm

Hello I downloaded a react project from https://github.com/fabiau/jc-calendar and when I do npm start I get error messages. I tried to do "NPM Fund" and "NPM Update" and none of them worked. Obviously i have no clue what I am doing so if anyone can point me in the right direction I would apprecaite it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before starting dev server you'll have to install the dependencies of the project using **npm install** , as generally node_modules/dependencies are not part of the repository.
This is mentioned in Readme.md of JC-calender.[image]

Comment: Yes I already did non install my mistake I should have mentioned this

Answer (score 0):

Checkout scripts in package.json in usual case start will be as given below but as per the code you consider npm-run-all package is used so be sure to run `npm install`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
  },
```

This may help you out https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting folder **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** if exists and run command `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

most of the repositories on GitHub, don't have **dependencies** installed, after downloading a repository on your local machine, you need to run **"npm install"**. The reason behind this is that **npm** will look for  all the required dependencies of the specified project and install them on your machine, with **node-modules**, then run **"npm start"**